# Deposit to Binance with version 15.0.1

Tags: binance

The GUI wallet doesn't give me an option to include a payment ID and Binance requires it. Possible settings like those in version 14 no longer show. How do I send XMR to Binance now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/e240ye/payment_id_removed_in_v01501_binance_didnt_update/

Comment: Binance has completed the upgrade: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/e4ywbk/binance_completes_monero_scheduled_protocol/

Answer (score 1):

Long, unencrypted payment IDs have been removed from Monero since v0.15. Only standard addresses, subaddresses and integrated addresses (which embed an encrypted payment ID), can be used now.

Binance have [announced](https://www.binance.com/en/support/articles/360036940012) (2019/11/28) that they will be supporting the update and will be following up with further details when they reopen deposits and withdrawals for XMR.